# HTMX progressively enhanced SPA inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inline, htmx

I fear I may have hi-jacked an issue on HTMX github. The problem is loosely related but think it maybe an issue that all the Hotwire/HTMX progressively enhanced web apps may have to deal with.

https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/464

Basically how to manage page specific js within a HTMX boosted app and falling foul of variable already initialised/declared.

Comment: Please read [ask] and create [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.